# Travel around Venice?

Tags: italy, venice

I'd like to know If I travel from Venice to Trieste would I see interesting places to visit?  I should also mention that I am traveling by train,  if this route is not interesting, what route do you suggest me?

Comment: Trieste is one of my favourite cities of all time, it's interesting from the get-go, and about the route train is fine. There's a enclave for the very wealthy at Grado which is worth the visit. The preferred alternate route from Venice to Trieste is by water taxi across the lagoon, which absolutely rocks.

Comment: What do you mean "move" ? stay in Trieste instead of Venice and still visit Venice ?

Comment: Sorry I meant traveling actually, I corrected the question

Comment: When I travelled same route I've checked Santuario Monte Grisa in suburbs of Trieste, there is a perfect view for Trieste and seacost. But If I'm in Venice again, I would rather continue travelling the other side of it - to Rome, visiting all the cities on the route or to the Milano through Verona as previous time, or stayed at Venice more time. I would visit Trieste again just if I travel to Croatia, where the mystic Rieka is just on the border with Italy.

Comment: Nothing to see by train, and regional trains are quite bad.... Cities to see: Lignano (summer vacations), Grado, Porto Piccolo (in Sistiana bay) and then Trieste.